# Fusionchart , XML , render fault

Tags: php, simplexml, fusioncharts

I have the following script that creates an XML string for rendering a chart with Fusionchart

```
<?php
 include("includes/fusioncharts.php");
 $chart = new SimpleXMLElement("<chart></chart>");
 $chart->addAttribute('caption', 'testgrafiek');
 $chart->addAttribute('subcaption', 'onderlabel');
 $chart->addAttribute('xaxisname', 'naam');
 $chart->addAttribute('yaxisname', 'aantal ronden');
 $categories = $chart->addChild('categories');
 $category[0] = $categories->addChild('category');
 $category[1] = $categories->addChild('category');
 $category[0] ->addAttribute('label', 'alias1');
 $category[1]->addAttribute('label', 'alias2');

$dataset1 = $chart->addChild('dataset');
$dataset1->addAttribute('seriesname', 'Revenues');
$dataset1det[0] = $dataset1->addChild('set');
$dataset1det[0] ->addAttribute('value', '16000');
$dataset1det[1] = $dataset1->addChild('set');
$dataset1det[1] ->addAttribute('value', '18000');

$dataset2 = $chart->addChild('dataset');
$dataset2->addAttribute('seriesname', 'Profits');
$dataset2->addAttribute('renderas', 'line');
$dataset2det[0] = $dataset2->addChild('set');
$dataset2det[0] ->addAttribute('value', '1000');
$dataset2det[1] = $dataset2->addChild('set');
$dataset2det[1] ->addAttribute('value', '8000');

$columnChart = new FusionCharts("column3D", "myFirstChart" , 700, 400, "chart-1", "xml", $chart);
$columnChart->render();

Header('Content-type: text/xml');
echo $chart->asXML();
?>
<div id="chart-1"><!-- Fusion Charts will render here--></div>
```

If I run the code above, I have an error on the page like

```
This page contains the following errors:

error on line 7 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
```

If I run the code without

```
$columnChart = new FusionCharts("column3D", "myFirstChart" , 700, 400, "chart-1", "xml", $chart);
$columnChart->render();
```

and

I have no errors on the page and see a correct XML.

Don't find how to solve this.

Someone?

Comment: Check what xml you generated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mix text/html output with XML, then you need to format the XML yourself and HTML encode it so the browser doesn't try to interpret the tags.

Firstly you need to understand that what type of header you are using there so that output should be in that format.

Example :

```
header("Content-Type: text/xml;"); //gives the output in xml format

header("Content-Type: text/php;"); //gives the output in php format

header("Content-Type: text/html;"); //gives the output in html format
```

I have used your code and have got rid of the issue you were facing, it was just that to see the output in the **html** format, you have to use `header("Content-Type: text/html;");`

The issue has been solved but your data is insufficient to get a chart, so by using a Sufficient data you will be able to see your desired chart.